# Erro '70': Permissão Negada

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Quando executo o código abaixo, aparece o erro do título na linha do 'For Each'. Isso é um bloqueio do próprio site ou tem algum erro no código?

```
Declara função Sleep
If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
End If

Sub IPMO_semanal()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument


    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.navigate "http://ons.org.br/pt/paginas/conhecimento/acervo-digital/documentos-e-publicacoes?categoria=Relat%C3%B3rio+PMO"
    IE.Visible = True

Set el = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("table")

    Sleep 2000

    i = 1
    For Each link In el.getElementsByTagName("a")

    '      If EXTRAIRELEMENTO(link.href, 9, "/") = "InformePMO_MAR2018_RV4.pdf" Then
    '      If Mid(link.href, 105, 8) = "InformePMO" Then

           If link.href = "http://ons.org.br/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=http://ons.org.br/AcervoDigitalDocumentosEPublicacoes/InformePMO_MAR2018_RV4.pdf" Then
            i = i + 1

            link.Click
             Sleep 2000
            If i = 2 Then Exit For
        End If

    Next link


End Sub
```

Comment: Não apareceu o mesmo erro para mim com este código.

Answer (score 1):

Rodou aqui, com um pequeno detalhe:

A variável `el` é uma coleção de tabelas (ainda que contenha uma única tabela), portanto foi necessário alterar o `For` para referenciar o primeiro elemento de `el` (ou seja, `el(0)`):

```
For Each link In el(0).getElementsByTagName("a")
```

De qualquer forma, não identificou nenhuma ocorrência do link que você especificou.